# iOS: Dereferencing NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

**When someone votes down the question... kindly please also comment why you had voted it down.**

I have a `UIView` (myHolderView) on which I want to place 9 or more other `views`.
I added some `UIView` (MyView) instances to an `NSMutableArray` of 9 elements (`MyArray`).

MyView has a label (`UILabel`) on it.  Can someone please assist how to get label's text using `MyArray`?

Note:

- I am seeing the UIViews added to main holder view and getting labels on it.
- `initWithFrame:(v,v,v,v) number: (value)` is the `init` method I had overloaded init with.

  //These two are declared as global variable

  ```
  NSMutableArray *tiles;
  MyView *tile;

  @implementation ViewController
  @synthesize myHolderView;
  -  (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  tiles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9];

  for (int xIndex=0; xIndex<3; xIndex++)
  {
      for(int yIndex=0; yIndex<3; yIndex++)
      {
          static int label=0;
          [tiles addObject:[[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(value,value,value,value)
                              number:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",label+1]]];

              [self.myHolderView addSubview:tiles[label]];

          //Now - when I want to print the labels onto Console as NSLog messages 
          //it is printing null

          MyView *n=[[MyView alloc]init];
          n=(MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:label++];
          NSLog(@"%@---",  n.myLabel.text);

          //this also does not work. Definitely wrong dereferencing
          //            NSLog(@"%@---",  (MyView*) [tiles ObjectAtIndex:1].mylabel.text);

          //label++;

          }
      }
  }
  ```

Please help

> how to dereference NSMuableArray objects to the type what we want (the
>   type we know it exactly)

MyView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame number:(NSString *)num;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        MyView *tile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        tile.myLabel.text=num;
        [self addSubview:tile];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why in your loop are you not just creating a new instance and referencing it? Your use of `label++` is likely to cause you issues as  your approach is messy

Comment: I tried that too! And if you see I commented label++ as separate statement.   My design had to be changed and I need to have a reference of the views that are created.  So, I wanted to hold their references in some array.  So, I need the views to be added to array.  Can you please suggest how to dereference the objects of that NSMutableArray into MyView ?

Comment: If you added your subview to holderview, it already hold its. then Why do you hold it again?

Comment: @iMani: I want to hold it because I need to make changes to their labels afterwards depends on the user's interaction with app.  Unless I hold their addresses in array, i will not be able to CATCH a particular view and change it.  Its just like I want their addresses in an array and I want to deference it when I need it.  Can you please help?

Comment: Well, there is no occurrence of "MyArray" in your code, so the first step would be to create it and populate it.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `MyView *n=[[MyView alloc]init];` and then writing over `n` in the very next line??

Comment: (I'd bet real money that you never created your array in the first place.)

Comment: NSMutableArray *tiles;
tiles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9];
This one does not create ?

Comment: Stop at `n=(MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:label++];` and type `po tiles` in the console.  What do you see?

Comment: @HotLicks : MyView: 0x10900d8e0; frame = (90 5; 10 10); layer = <CALayer: 0x109038010>>

Comment: So no surrounding `()` characters?  That would mean it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is nothing to do with arrays or dereferencing. It's a logical issue because you are creating multiple views and nesting them.

Change the implementation of `MyView`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame number:(NSString *)num;
{
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.frame = frame;
    self.myLabel.text = num;

    return self;
}
```

---

Try something like this (typed inline so watch for issues):

```
-  (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];

    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    for (int xIndex=0; xIndex<3; xIndex++)
    {
        for(int yIndex=0; yIndex<3; yIndex++)
        {
            MyView *newView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(value,value,value,value) number:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", counter+1]]];
            [self.myHolderView addSubview:newView];

            [tiles addObject:newView];

            MyView *logView = (MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:counter];
            NSLog(@"view %d is %@---", counter, logView.myLabel.text);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NSLog(@"view %d is %@---", counter, ((MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:counter]).myLabel.text);
((MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:counter]).
after DOT operator… the option is not myLabel but MyView etc. I don’t think the dereferencing level is right.

Comment: MyView *n=(MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:label];
            NSLog(@"%@--%d",n.myLabel.text, label);
n.myLabel.text is (null) where as label is coming 0, 1, 2 etc. for every iteration.

Comment: Which suggests that the label isn't being created when you call `initWithFrame` on `MyView` - check the implementation, when is the label created?

Comment: But the label is being printed on the View with the incremented value every time. Means, it got created.

Comment: - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame number:(NSString *)num;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    
    if (self) {
        MyView *tile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        tile.myLabel.text=num;
        [self addSubview:tile];
    }
    return self;
}

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want to add some view to your holderview. Later, you want to change text in particular view. So I suggest some way. I think, It will help you..

1) create and Add subview to your holder view

```
for (int xIndex=0; xIndex<9; xIndex++)
{
       MyView *subView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(value,value,value,value)
                            number:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",somecount+1]]]; // doesn't know why do you try this..
       subView.tag = xIndex;
       [self.myHolderView addSubview: subView];

}
```

2) Get particular subview with tag value.(No need to maintain any other array in your view controller)
After some time, you want to change text in particular view. Just try  it..

```
MyView *subView = [self.myHolderView viewWithTag:index]; // as like, you access array
subView.myLabel.text = yourUpdateText;
```

Comment: The type casting won't work. MyView is having label. where as myHolderView is just a plain view.  And, I typecasted it - which would generally crash the app for obvious reasons. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Chandu My friend, where did you see type casting in my code?

Comment: Not explicit brother!  Implicit.  The LHS is not in compatible type with RHS.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MyView : UIView
@property UILabel *myLabel;
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) rect number: (NSString *) string;
@end

@implementation MyView
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame number: (NSString *) number {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;
    // Any things here
    // Are you initialized label?
    _myLabel = [UILabel new];
    [_myLabel setText:number];
    [self addSubview:_myLabel];
    return self;
}
@end

@interface ViewController ()
@property UIView *myHolderView;
@end

NSMutableArray *tiles;
MyView *tile;

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myHolderView;
-  (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tiles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9];
    int value = 1, label = 0;
    myHolderView = [UIView new];

    for (int xIndex=0; xIndex<3; xIndex++) {
        for(int yIndex=0; yIndex<3; yIndex++) {
            NSString *number = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",label+1];
            MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(value,value,value,value)
                                                   number:number];
            [tiles addObject:myView];

            [self.myHolderView addSubview:tiles[label]];

            //Now - when I want to print the labels onto Console as NSLog messages
            //it is printing number

            MyView *n=(MyView *)[tiles objectAtIndex:label++];
            NSLog(@"%@---",  n.myLabel.text);
        }
    }

    // And without tiles array
    for (UIView *subView in [myHolderView subviews])
        for (UIView *subSubView in [subView subviews])
            if ([subSubView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                NSLog(@"%@", [(UILabel *) subSubView text]);
}
@end
```